# List comprehension with if() condition replacement

Tags: python

How to replace if() statements for 2 variables of list comprehension to one complex if comprehension with if() statement.

Replace this part:

```py
if dictit["any"]:
    listit = [
        dictit["all"] + [x]
        for x in dictit["any"]
    ]
else:
    listit = [dictit["all"]]
```

In example:

```py
first = {
    "all": []
    , "any": []
}

second = {
    "all": ["1", "2"]
    , "any": ["Student", "Master"]
}

third = {
    "all": []
    , "any": ["Student", "Master"]
}

forth = {
    "all": ["1", "2"]
    , "any": []
}

all_vars = [
    first
    , second
    , third
    , forth
]

for dictit in all_vars:
    if dictit["any"]:
        listit = [
            dictit["all"] + [x]
            for x in dictit["any"]
        ]
    else:
        listit = [dictit["all"]]

    print(listit)
```

Result:

```py
[[]]
[['1', '2', 'Student'], ['1', '2', 'Master']]
[['Student'], ['Master']]
[['1', '2']]
```

Like this, but it is not working:

```py
    listit = [
        dictit["all"] + [x]
        if dictit["any"] else dictit["all"]
        for x in dictit["any"]
    ]
```

Please, share your code.
Thank you for your time and support.

Comment: So do you want the above code to be a single list comprehension? So something like this? `listit = [dictit["all"] + [x] for x in dictit["any"]] if dictit["any"] else list(dictit["all"])`

Comment: Only part of it, where if() statement

Comment: Does my comment work?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking

Comment: Does it have to be a list comprehension or do you only want a one-liner?

Comment: @CozyCode Tank you for your answer, it is working. But I had the same problem, it is working only when you place if() statement after list comprehension as you did. Can `(if dictit["any"] else list(dictit["all"]))` be placed in conprehension ?

Comment: Question edited...

Comment: @Matthias , List comprehension, not in line. The answer of user: "CozyCode" is working, but it is huge in line. The answer of user: "Kelly Bundy" , is very clear and short, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this:

```
listit = [
    dictit["all"] + [x]
    for x in dictit["any"]
] or [dictit["all"]]
```

Comment: looks short and esthetic. Thank you very much. This part is what I am missing `or [dictit["all"]]` .

Comment: I cannot rate your answer as USEFUL because I do not have reputation, but your answer is best. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
[[x['all'] + [y] for y in x['any']] if x['any'] else [x['all']] for x in all_vars]
```

output:

```
[[[]],
 [['1', '2', 'Student'], ['1', '2', 'Master']],
 [['Student'], ['Master']],
 [['1', '2']]]
```

Comment: It is not working as expected

Comment: I think the new one match the output exactly

Comment: @Z Li , to much lines at output

Comment: this one is used to replace your whole for loop

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this would be a good use for `itertools.product`. Unfortunately, the pre- and post-processing you need make this, well, not the most readable.

```
for dictit in all_vars:
    all_things = dictit["all"]
    any_things = dictit["any"]
    print([list(chain(*t)) for t in product([all_things], [[v] for v in any_things] or [[]])])
```